# How to remove OTRS ? (as it uses 20% CPU)

Tags: uninstall, cpu-load, otrs

OTRS (Open-source Ticket Request System) is constantly using 15 to 20% of my CPU, making my passive cooling computer too hot.
How do I remove it? The daemon name is *otrs.Daemon.pl* in the Task Manager.

Also, is it safe to do so ? My understanding is that it is used to report troubles back to Ubuntu, but in this case it is the trouble.

For the moment, I simply pause the task in the Task Manager, and the CPU usage drops back to 0-5% keeping the computer at pretty low temperatures.

Comment: What is OTRS? Would it be the "Open Ticket Request System"?

Comment: Yes it is, from what I understand. The daemon name is : otrs.Daemon.pl in the task manager.

Comment: How did you install it? The binaries are not seeded in Ubuntu, so it shouldn't be installed by default.

Comment: I have no memory installing it, but maybe you're right. Does that mean I can safely remove it ?

Comment: Well that's a decision only you can make. But simply removing the `otrs` or `otrs2` package should do (not sure what you installed). If something else gets removed with it, apt will tell you and ask you for confirmation first.

Comment: I was unable to remove otrs, not even find it, because it was otrs2 installed. I have probably installed it ages ago and forgot about it, and it's been using CPU for years... Now I have been able to remove it. Thank you @dobey you helped me on this.

Comment: you can add an answer below explaining how you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove OTRS (The "Open Ticket Request System") that was using too much CPU, I had to remove the package otrs2 using this command :

```
sudo apt remove otrs2
```

The trick was that I was looking for an "otrs" package which was not present and nothing led me to find out the package name was "otrs2". User @dobey gave me the solution, thank you.

It is totally safe to remove otrs, Ubuntu does not depend on it.

Comment: next time use this to find it - sudo apt-cache search otrs